# React iframe load event not firing after changing src attribute by state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We are building a sign up form for a React application which embeds a HTML legal agreement as iframe. The document is available in multiple languages , one of which can be selected by a dropdown menu, this option is independent from the application's global i18n preference.

Our legal department doesn't really like us touching their docs so converting it to JSX isn't an option, they also want us to make sure the user has "read" the agreement by requiring the document to be scrolled to the bottom before the checkbox agreeing to it is enabled.

We attempted to implement this by registering a load listener on the iframe's contentWindow inside a useEffect hook that registers a scroll listener on contentDocument when the iframe has finished loading. The scroll listener then enables the "I agree" checkbox when the user has finished reading the iframe document.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");
  const [tncRead, setTncRead] = useState(false);

  const iframeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (iframeRef) {
      const currentRef = iframeRef.current;
      // Wait for the iframe document to finish loading
      iframeRef.current.contentWindow.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log("onLoad fired");
        // Register the scroll listener
        iframeRef.current.contentDocument.addEventListener(
          "scroll",
          handleOnScroll
        );
      });

      return () => {
        if (currentRef) {
          console.log("unregistered listener");
          currentRef.contentDocument.removeEventListener(
            "scroll",
            handleOnScroll
          );
        }
      };
    }
  }, [language]);

  function handleLanguageChange(e) {
    setLanguage(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleOnScroll(e) {
    const scrollingElement = e.target.scrollingElement;
    const hasReachedBottom =
      scrollingElement.scrollHeight - scrollingElement.clientHeight <=
      scrollingElement.scrollTop + 50;
    if (!tncRead && hasReachedBottom) {
      setTncRead(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label>Language :</label>
        <select onChange={handleLanguageChange}>
          <option value="en">English</option>
          <option value="zh">中文</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <iframe ref={iframeRef} id="tnc-frame" src={`tnc_${language}.html`} />
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" disabled={!tncRead} />
        <label>I agree to the Terms & Conditions</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-iframe-onload-test-forked-q76qzs?file=/src/App.js

However this only works on the initial render of the component. If the user changes the state controlling the iframe's src attribute by selecting a different language, the load listener registering the scroll listener doesn't fire which causes the checkbox to never enable.

I tried the same in vanilla JavaScript and it worked there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using use effect and managing state for just to listen for scroll is unnecessary as you can simply use 'onLoad' on iframe element to listen for load event eath time it gets rerendered , i have seen your codesandbox and taking it as reference

so you can simply remove whole useEffect block and just add this in iframe

```
<iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        onLoad={(e) => {
          e.target.contentDocument.onscroll = handleOnScroll;
        }}
        id="tnc-frame"
        src={`tnc_${language}.html`}
/>
```

and to change tncRead

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTncRead(false);
  }, [language]);
```

additionally if you see , i have used onscroll instead of addEventListener so it wont register multiple event listeners , it just overwites previous listener